# why this Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

anybody can explain to me why this code produce that error?

```
$("#crop-canvas-draw").on("click tap", function(e){
        var pageX = device == 'touch' ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX:e.pageX;
        var pageY = device == 'touch' ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY:e.pageY;
        var x = pageX - $("#crop-canvas-primary").offset().left;
        var y = pageY - $("#crop-canvas-primary").offset().top;

        var replaceColor = 0;

        /*
         * scan
         * - top
         * - bottom
         * - left
         * - right
         * */
        var scan = function(x, y){
            var imgData = ctxDraw.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
            var data = imgData.data; // data is one dimension array
            if(data[0] == 0 && data[1] == 0 && data[2] == 0){
                data[0] = 0;
                data[1] = 0;
                data[2] = 255;
                data[3] = 255;
                ctxDraw.putImageData(imgData, x, y);
                // re-scan
                scan((x-1), y);
                scan((x+2), y);
                scan(x, (y-1));
                scan(x, (y+2));
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }
        scan(x, y);
    });
```

i am trying to create paint bucket in my canvas app, i don't know why it's produce that error.

updated script for conditioning when reaching out the far left/top/right/bottom.

```
$("#crop-canvas-draw").on("click tap", function(e){
        var pageX = device == 'touch' ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX:e.pageX;
        var pageY = device == 'touch' ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY:e.pageY;
        var x = pageX - $("#crop-canvas-primary").offset().left;
        var y = pageY - $("#crop-canvas-primary").offset().top;

        var replaceColor = 0;

        /*
         * scan
         * - top
         * - bottom
         * - left
         * - right
         * */
        var scan = function(x, y){
            var imgData = ctxDraw.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
            var data = imgData.data; // data is one dimension array
            if(data[0] == 0 && data[1] == 0 && data[2] == 0){
                data[0] = 0;
                data[1] = 0;
                data[2] = 255;
                data[3] = 255;
                ctxDraw.putImageData(imgData, x, y);
                // re-scan
                if((y == 0 || y == cvsDraw.height) && (x == 0 || x == cvsDraw.width)) return;
                scan((x-1), y);
                scan((x+2), y);
                scan(x, (y-1));
                scan(x, (y+2));
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }
        scan(x, y);
    });
```

Comment: It has to be a problem with your recursive function, that's why the stack blows up. The exit condition is not being reached at some point.

Comment: Looks like there is no base case for the recursion. That would cause infinite recursion, leading to your error.

Comment: alright, can you show me how to create the case for reaching the far left/top/right/bottom?

Comment: @DarielPratama **Think about it** a bit. When you reach the sides of the image, then what coordinates are you at? Now program that condition into your function.

Comment: @user3477950 please see updated question. still error, and still finding a way to clear that error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this was supposed to serve as your method of stopping the recursion:

```
if(data[0] == 0 && data[1] == 0 && data[2] == 0){
```

Unfortunately, when you call getImageData on an out-of-bounds pixel, it returns transparent black (see the spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-getimagedata)). You could update your condition to be:

```
if(data[0] == 0 && data[1] == 0 && data[2] == 0 && 
   x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x <= cvsDraw.width && y <= cvsDraw.height){
```

That should make sure you don't go out of bounds.

**Note:** The reason your updated solution fails

```
if((y == 0 || y == cvsDraw.height) && (x == 0 || x == cvsDraw.width)) return;
```

is because you are checking if you are *exactly* on the border. However, you are sometimes shifting your coordinates by increments of 2, meaning that you may skip over the exact edge.